# Drupal Better Exposed Filters - abort Ajax request

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-views

I use Drupal 7 with Views 3. I have installed Better Exposed Filters module. I'm exposing some filters and I use ajax, so when i change checkbox or select value for example there goes ajax request. Generally everything works fine.

But there's an issue with I can't handle with:/
Basicly, when I change the select value, ajax request is send. Before result from this request I change select value again, but there's no ajax request. 
I can't send another ajax request or abort existing one.

So my question is, how to abort this ajax request and immediatly send next one?

Comment: If possible, you could disable all checkboxes/selects while the ajax request is being made, and activate them again when the ajax request is done. (I think jQuery ajaxStart and ajaxStop functions can help you with that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, and managed to solve it without having to modify any core files. The idea is to listen for jQuery's global ajaxSend() event, store the jqXHR object for the current request, then in the click handler for your filters, check if the request has completed yet and abort if it hasn't. So the code will look something like:

```
var filterXHR = null;
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqXHR, settings) {
  filterXHR = jqXHR; // cache XHR object for current ajax request
});

// event handler for when a filter is selected/changed/etc.
$('#filters-block .form-item a').click(function () {

  // check if there is a previous request that has not yet completed
  if (filterXHR && filterXHR.readyState != 4) {
    // abort ajax request
    filterXHR.abort();

    // subsequent requests will add their own progress indicator,
    // so you probably want to remove the old one here 
    $('.ajax-progress').remove(); 
  }

  // submit exposed form, do other stuff, etc.. 
});
```

[I know its generally bad internet etiquette to resurrect old posts, but since this was the first (and only) meaningful result that came up on google when I was looking for info, I figured it would be appropriate to share my solution here for the benefit of others who may have similar issues and end up landing on this page.]

Answer (score 0):

In fact I have manage it:)

I overwrite some prototypes in ajax.js in Drupal folder.

- Change the conditional: `if (ajax.ajaxing){ ... }`
- Turned off disabling submit element
- Add `current_ajax` variable for current ajax
  request so I can do `current_ajax.abort();`

Comment: Kevin's answer below much better - no need to modify core files:) Thx mate!